# Manually update ListView with a Thread in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, listview, javafx

I'm developing a mailbox and I would like that the client automatically checks if there are new emails. I made this by using a thread which loops until I close the client and that if sees that the current number of emails on the list is different from the number of files on the server it reloads the data and adds the new email. It works, but every time I get an update on the list I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListCellSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ListCellSkin.java:49)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
at mailbox.ListController$1.updateItem(ListController.java:56)
at mailbox.ListController$1.updateItem(ListController.java:49)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:471)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.access$300(ListCell.java:72)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell$2.changed(ListCell.java:185)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell$2.changed(ListCell.java:175)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView.setItems(ListView.java:390)
at mailbox.ListController$2.run(ListController.java:71)
```

This is my ListView Controller code:

```
public class ListController {

@FXML
private ListView<Email> listView;
private DataModel model;
private int NoE;

public void initModel(DataModel model) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model;

    model.loadData();

    listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());

    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection)
            -> model.setCurrentEmail(newSelection));
    model.currentEmailProperty().addListener((obs, oldEmail, newEmail) -> {
        if (newEmail == null) {
            listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        } else {
            listView.getSelectionModel().select(newEmail);
        }
    });

    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Email>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Email mail, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(mail, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else if (mail != null) {
                setText(mail.getMittente());
            }
        }
    });

    NoE = model.getNumberOfEmail();
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int current = model.askNumbOfEmail();
                    if (NoE != current) {
                        NoE = current;
                        model.reLoadData();
                        listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    System.out.println("ParseException ERROR!");
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this line

```
 listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());
```

inside [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
 Platform.runLater(() -> listView.setItems(model.getEmailList()));
```